# Loss does not decrease while training with PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, hungarian-algorithm

Im going with PyTorch for neural net training. Im trying to train my net to be a replacement for Hungarian algorhythm. I have neural net for each row in cost matrix with size 500x500 - list with 500 lists that contains of 500 elements each. For training I pass one specific row (list with 500 elements) from each matrix as an input and index of assignment as an output. Batch size is ten. So each batch contains of list with 10 lists contains of 500 elements each and list with 10 integers as indexes that have been assigned to each row.

```
[tensor([[225., 297.,  69.,  ..., 169., 223.,   3.],
        [107., 225.,   2.,  ...,  95., 272.,  85.],
        [126.,  37., 108.,  ..., 116., 225., 278.],
        ...,
        [ 33., 158.,  55.,  ..., 182., 266.,  23.],
        [258.,  11., 103.,  ...,  31., 218., 289.],
        [  7., 113., 170.,  ...,  31., 275., 289.]]), tensor([329, 271,  40, 460, 466, 375, 206, 426, 263, 380])]
```

First element of this pair I pass as an input of net and second for loss calculation

```
m_size = 500

class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fullyConnectedLayer1 = nn.Linear(500, 100)
        self.fullyConnectedLayer2 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.fullyConnectedLayer3 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.fullyConnectedLayer4 = nn.Linear(100, 500)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fullyConnectedLayer1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fullyConnectedLayer2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fullyConnectedLayer3(x))
        x = self.fullyConnectedLayer4(x)
        return f.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    netBunch = []
    optBunch = []

    preTensorFt = []
    preTensorLbl = []

    for nnet in range(m_size):
        net = Net()
        optimizer = opt.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)

        netBunch.append(net)
        optBunch.append(optimizer)

    loss = None
    for net in range(len(netBunch)):
        neural = netBunch[net]
        optim = optBunch[net]

        for epoch in range(3):

            preTensorFt = []
            preTensorLbl = []
            batch = []

            for sample in range(80000):
                i_file = str(sys.path[0]) + '\\dataset\\in_sample_{0}.txt'.format(sample)
                o_file = str(sys.path[0]) + '\\dataset\\out_sample_{0}.txt'.format(sample)

                matrix = parse.parse_from_file(i_file, m_size)
                res_mx = parse.parse_from_file(o_file, m_size)

                preTensorFt.append(matrix[net])
                preTensorLbl.append(res_mx[net].index(1))

                if (sample % 10 == 9) and (sample != 0):
                    tensorFt = torch.tensor(preTensorFt, dtype=torch.float32)
                    tensorLbl = torch.LongTensor(preTensorLbl)

                    batch.append([tensorFt, tensorLbl])

                    preTensorFt = []
                    preTensorLbl = []

                    for pair in batch:

                        X, y = pair

                        neural.zero_grad() 
                        output = neural(X)
                        loss = f.nll_loss(output, y)

                        loss.backward()
                        optim.step()
                    batch = []
                    print('Loss after batch calc = {0}'.format(loss))
            print(loss)
```

As I imagine, I have to pass a batch of rows as an input and a batch of assigned for this row indexes as an output

But in the end loss stops around 6.2 and never decreases more. May be Im losing some of basic concepts. Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Why are you training 500 models?

Comment: I want to prepare one model for each row in cost matrix and run them in parallel to solve it

Comment: Ok, still not sure why but I was just curious. Couple of notes (might not solve your problem), but you should normalise/standardise your data, and your batching is wrong (it grows continually through your epoch, so your first batch is trained on 80000 times/epoch whereas your last batch is just trained upon once). You should look at PyTorch datasets and data loaders.